# XLL plugin's DDEConnect() fails when connecting to Excel?

Tags: excel, dde, xll

I have a problem with connecting to Excel, there's a plugin that reads from db and tries to fill excel sheet with data across DDE, and it seems to be failing sometimes on DDEConnect function with error number 16390 - DMLERR_INVALIDPARAMETER Invalid parameter to DDEML function call.

What is more interesting it is failing more often when pressing F9 (recalculates all formula in worksheet) then running from macro which goes through all worksheets and recalculates the formulae.

Anybody with experience of DDE with Excel?

Regards,
Mika

Comment: Kinda late - but whenever excel is busy - dde and com calls will be failed. Solution is to retry the call or better still - make sure the call is made on the ui thread - eg - have a button on the ribbon trigger the dde call.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that DdeInitialize() was not yet called for the current thread

Comment: thanks for help but didn't find any reasonable explanation, it's a blackbox and it just didn't work for me...